# Does Secure Keyboard Entry Prevent All Forms of Keyloggers?

Tags: macos, security

I had an understanding that [Secure Keyboard Entry](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/01/secure-keyboard-entry-brings-more-security-to-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x/) (or [EnableSecureEventInput](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2150/_index.html)) was a feature that essentially disabled keyloggers.

Is that the case? Are there ways around it?

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct but:

Using the Secure keyboard Entry (on screen key board) will not keep some supper hacker from using the screen capture to see what you entering.

That is assuming you have a serious bug on your system.

Comment: Not really relevant as Secure Keyboard Entry is mostly for entering passwords, and "echo" is turned off in this case so there's nothing to capture from the screen except for the length of passwords